# Interaction between await and try {} finally {}

Tags: javascript, async-await, finally

I have this simple async function:

```
async function do_stuff() {
    try {
        console.log("Start")
        await inner_func();
    }
    finally {
        console.log("At finally");
    }
}
```

to my surprise this prints:
`Start`
`At finally`
`(things from the async inner_func)`

Now, conceptually I can understand why this happens, `await` returns a Promise from `do_stuff` and returning from the function invokes the `finally` but this seem to violate the whole point of `await` - that it gives the illusion that the code is being run sequentially

So the right solution seem to be to take the promise and call `finally()` on it, but that looks strange since I would need to duplicate the code in the `finally {}` twice

Comment: hm, well, try executes and finally executes (synchronously) after sync is over the microqueue pushes to the stack...

Comment: Not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/4hnLkwpu/ If something happens after `finally` it only means `inner_func` scheduled it to be run later, not corresponding to its returned promise.

Comment: Can you share the code of `inner_func`?